# get Timezone in format of UTC+5:30

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, utc

I want to get timezone of user in String formatted like `UTC+5:30`

I have tried to get like this.

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSLog(@"%@   ||   %@",timeZone.abbreviation,timeZone.name);
```

This gives me this output.
 (but not getting time as i want)

> IST        ||          Asia/Kolkata

Thanks

Comment: what the answer you expected for e.g +5.30 or UTC+5:30

Comment: UTC+5:30 would be preferable

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSDate Formatter to get the offset from UTC:

```
NSDateFormatter *dates = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dates setDateFormat:@"Z"];    
NSLog(@"%@", [dates stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

This will log: +0530 (+5:30)

If you want it in your specific format you can simply do:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"Z"];

NSString *offetString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UTC%@:%@",[offetString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)],[offetString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([offetString length] - 2, 2)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
df.dateFormat = @"Z";
NSString *localTimeZoneOffset = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",localTimeZoneOffset);
```

You will get output like,

`+0530` for `UTC+5:30`.

**Update :** (As asked in comment)

Try below code for your desired format,

```
  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
df.dateFormat = @"Z";
NSString *localTimeZoneOffset = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",localTimeZoneOffset);

NSString *one = [localTimeZoneOffset substringToIndex:1];
NSString *two = [localTimeZoneOffset substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)];
NSString *three = [localTimeZoneOffset substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 2)];

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"utc%@%@:%@",one,two,three];

NSLog(@"result : %@",result);
```